# column chart with negative values and centered labeles js

Tags: javascript, html, charts, frontend, canvasjs

I am trying to make a very simple chart with negative values and centered labels,

I have tried everything and this stupid thing won't work, I found some examples, dint work either, if anyone here build a chart like this and could share the code, or help me with , i will relay REALLY appreciate it. please,
I am using canvasJS.

I need something like this:

[image]

*sorry for bad English please help thank you.

**this is my basic chart, (if needed):**

```
window.onload = function () {

    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {

      axisY:{
          gridThickness: 0,

      },
      axisX:{
       title: "",
       tickLength: 0,
       margin:0,
       lineThickness:0,
       valueFormatString:" ",
      },

      data: [
      {
        type: "bar",
        dataPoints: [
        { y: -3.5 },
        { y: -3.89 },
        { y: 4.5 },
        { y: 5 }, 
        { y: 4 }, 
        ]
      }
      ]
    });

 chart.render();
}
```

Comment: based on their examples, it seems you're simply missing the x value in your data `{ x: 10, y: -71 }` . see their demo [here](https://canvasjs.com/javascript-charts/chart-index-data-label/)

Comment: You mentioned you tried a few different strategies and none of them worked. Can you include the approaches you tried in the question since it can help other contributors cut down the surface area of what the issue might be?

Comment: I've edited to clean up the question. If you can provide example output or errors, that will help.